# TypeError: Params must be in a list, tuple, or Row. SQL database data insertion

Tags: python, sql, database

I have a Cloud Azure DB where I want to introduce some data from another csv files. I am doing this with Python.

Basically, I manually store in a json fie the equivalencies between my DB columns and the csv columns in this format:

```
{
    "csv_column_1": {
        "table": "table1",
        "db_column": "column1"
    },
    "csv_column_2": {
        "table": "table1",
        "db_column": "column2"
}
}
```

That way, I can iterate through it in a loop and insert it into my database with the following code.

```py
# Establish a connection to your SQL Server
conn = odbc.connect(connection_string)

# Create a cursor
cursor = conn.cursor()

for table, column, row in zip(tables, db_columns, data): 

    sqlinsert = f"INSERT INTO {table} ({column}) VALUES (?)"
    
    cursor.executemany(sqlinsert, row)
    cursor.commit()
    
print('Data inserted successfully.')
```

I have tried a lot of different codes and combinations and ways but no one works. I always get the error about `TypeError: Params must be in a list, tuple, or Row` which makes no sense cause my data is a list.

I have been able to introduce it but in a wrong way, columns are completely disorganized and it just appends rows while I want to keep the row level of my csv (basically inserting whole columns without minding about rows).

Comment: Please show examples of `tables`, `db_columns` ,and `data`. When you use `executemany, `row` should be a list of lists.

Comment: How is the JSON you show at the top related to this?

Comment: `INSERT` is for adding new rows to a table. If you want to change a column without adding new rows, you use `UPDATE`. But you need a `WHERE` clause to specify which row(s) to change.

Comment: If you want to add a new column to a table, you use `ALTER TABLE` and need to specify the datatype of the column.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your json.
I saw in your json structure that I was missing a brace.

Try this:

```
import odbc

data_mapping = {
    "csv_column_1": {
        "table": "table1",
        "db_column": "column1"
    },
    "csv_column_2": {
        "table": "table1",
        "db_column": "column2"
    }
}

data = [
    ["value1_row1", "value2_row1"],
    ["value1_row2", "value2_row2"]
]

connection_string = "your_connection_string_here"
conn = odbc.connect(connection_string)

cursor = conn.cursor()

for csv_column, mapping in data_mapping.items():
    table = mapping["table"]
    db_column = mapping["db_column"]
    column_index = int(csv_column.split("_")[-1]) - 1
    
    for row in data:
        value = row[column_index]
        sqlinsert = f"INSERT INTO {table} ({db_column}) VALUES (?)"
        
        cursor.execute(sqlinsert, value)
        conn.commit()

print('Data inserted successfully.')

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, 
Thank you for your help. There was no error in the json format, I just pasted it wrong into the post. 
I try what you sent me but I get this error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1111 1 (Weight) [no unit]'
Being the last part, a column from the csv I am trying to insert. Also, my data is not in tuples, I got columns of +50 instances. Do you mean that I should iterate over rows?